# Controlling the placement of the y-axis

Tags: plotting, ticks

I use `ListPlot` for showing the results of my numeric computation.

[image]

I make my own ticks, so I never know before hand where the vertical center of my plot will be. I want to put the y-axis in the center (because it's a center of symmetry in my task) of the plot by default. I know about `AxesOrigin`, but it doesn't take `Center` as a value. How can I put the y-axis in the center automatically without caring about ticks?

[image]

Comment: We really need to know the form of the data you give to`ListPlot` takes. Is it `{y1, y2, ..., yn}` or is it `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ..., {xn, yn}}`?

Comment: I use the first variant of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is just a list of y-ordinates.

```
data = Table[Exp[-x^2], {x, -2., 2., .1}];
lbls = Range[-2., 2., .5];
xTicks = {Rescale[#, {-2., 2.}, {1, Length@data1}], #} & /@ lbls;
```

The center of plot will be at `Length[data] + 1)/2.`, so `AxesOrigin` can be used to place the y-axis:

```
ListPlot[data,
  Joined -> True,
  Ticks -> {xTicks, Automatic},
  AxesOrigin -> {(Length[data] + 1)/2., Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You may use:

```
center[gr_Graphics] := Show[gr, AxesOrigin -> {Mean @ First @ PlotRange @ gr, 0}]
```

Example:

```
dat = Table[TriangleWave[x] + RandomReal[0.3], {x, 3/4, 7/4, 0.01}];

ListPlot[dat] // center
```

[image]

The code above assumes you want to place the horizontal axis at zero.  You could use `Automatic` instead for default placement, or if you wish to center *both* axes you can use:

```
centerXY[gr_Graphics] := Show[gr, AxesOrigin -> Mean /@ PlotRange @ gr]
```

---

As eldo commented and m_goldberg alluded to above if your data is of the form {y1, y2, y3, ...} you can use simply:  `AxesOrigin -> {Length@dat / 2, 0}`.  I felt that this was a trivial solution and unlikely to be the situation that precipitated the question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `Length@dat/2.` would give the same result: `50.5`

Comment: @eldo Only for data of the form {y1, y2, y3, ...}.  My method will also handle {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}.  I suppose I should include that point in the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think the latter case could be handled with `mid = (data[[-1, 1]] - data[[1, 1]])/2`

Comment: @eldo Frankly I didn't think of that.  You'll need to pick between those two forms based on the data (to make it universal) but that should be a good solution.  Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard How about you take my figures and I delete my answer? :) You get all the votes anyway ;o(

Answer (score 1):

Would something like that fit?

```
Module[{p = ListPlot[Thread@{Sort@RandomReal[{-500, 140}, 100], 
                             Sort@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]}, 
              Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> 300], r}, 
 r = PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[p, PlotRange]; 
 GraphicsRow@{p, Show[p, AxesOrigin -> {Mean@r[[1]], Automatic}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Well nuts.  I didn't see this answer before posting. (Blind?)  I just posted something very similar, though I think a bit cleaner.  Would you like me to edit your answer to include (or replace with) that, or shall I leave my answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't mind the two answers, the idea is the same but yours is cleaner indeed. Although I like my figures the most :D at least on can see the different before/after :)

Comment: Okay.  And I agree your plots look nicer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using Mr. Wizard's data the same plot could be obtained with

```
ListPlot[dat, AxesOrigin -> {Length@dat/2, 0}]
```

With given X-coordinates like in

```
dat = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {101, 10}};

mid = (dat[[-1, 1]] - dat[[1, 1]])/2.
```

> 50.5

```
ListLinePlot[dat, AxesOrigin -> {mid, 0}, PlotRange -> All]
```